# Can we run xcowsay on mac OSX? If yes, how?

Tags: macos, installation

I have currently switched to mac from linux and am missing **xcowsay**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcoway requires X, for linux that is x11 for mac you will ned toinstall Xquartz.

According to http://www.doof.me.uk/2008/03/04/xcowsay-on-os-x/, xcowsay is suported in mac since 2008.

Download and install XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/. Then download and compile xcowsay from https://github.com/nickg/xcowsay/

Answer (score 1):

I had to install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) on Mac OS X and build from source.

I used homebrew to install the dependencies and cloned from the source at https://github.com/nickg/xcowsay/. I ran into an issue with `autoreconf` finding the `autopoint` command from `gettext`. Adding the gettext bin folder to my path solved it.

See steps below

```
brew install autoconf gettext gdk-pixbuf gtk+
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for OSX.

`cowsay` is available via the homebrew package manager. I do not see the X-Server version of `cowsay`.

https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/cowsay.rb

Comment: xcowsay is not avaiable in homebrew. so it has to be complied from source. for details please read my answer.